# MediaWiki, display data aggregate from a template

Tags: mediawiki

I'm running MediaWiki version 1.27.4.

With a template I have added informations in a bounch of pages.

I would like to automatically obtain a table that aggregates all this data.

I found this extension https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Data_Aggregator but is very old and doesn't work on my MediaWiki version.

Thanks!

Comment: [Semantic MediaWiki](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/) can do that (and much, much more). Not trivial to set up, though.

Answer (score 0):

A newer extension capable writing data from templates into database tables is [Extension:Cargo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Extension:Cargo), which is easy to install and good if you trust all your users with write permissions not to do malicious stuff to your database, otherwise go with [Semantic MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_MediaWiki).

Ugly and very limited hack: If the template only adds one piece of information and you are okay messing with category sorting and you do not need to run aggregation operations, you might be able to put this single piece of information into the sort key. `[[Category:example|{{{information}}}]]`. You can then retrieve `{{{information}}}` from an [API query](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers) `action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=example&cmprop=sortkey|sortkeyprefix` or directly from the [`categorylinks` table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Categorylinks_table).